# How to set zoom-in max on TeeChart for a javascript?

Tags: javascript, teechart

we are trying to set zoom-in max for x axis with date format. For example after the last zoom-in the time distance between tick labels should be 20 seconds (15:33:40 15:34:00 15:34:20 15:34:40 15:35:00). For zoom we are using to set min/max from button.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

To zoom is actually to change the scale of one or several axes. You can use this to change the bottom axis scale:

```
Chart1.axes.bottom.setMinMax(min, max);
```